# How to add shadows and specular highlights in composting?

Tags: compositing-nodes, image, lighting, shadows

[image]

This is a scene that I have made in Blender:

The locations and angles of the lights and lamps are known to me [obviously].
I want to superimpose images on this rendered image through compositing such that i can add and adjust specular highlights and shadows respective to the lighting in the scene.

For example:
When this image:

[image]

is composited on the above scene after removing it's white background, looks like this:

[image]

However without the appropriate specular highlights and shadows, it doesn't feel like a 100% integrated part of the scene.

I know this can be easily achieved in the Adobe software suite, but I'd rather play Russian Roulette alone.

In summation, how do I:

(1) Composite shadows and specular highlights on an image?

(2) How can i make it easily adjustable to any image of my choosing?

Comment: To have something looking realistic, you would have to model at least a barely similar object. Of course that's not easily adjustable for any arbitrary image. Everything else like trying to convert the shape into some shadow overlay and distort it to the ground is maybe done easier in software like Gimp or Photoshop.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann i don't need it to look realistic, i just need to cheat the "lights" enough that it looks like a part of the scene and i need this system such that i can apply to any other image if required.

Comment: Maybe not realistic, but if you don't want to model it, it is just a flat image or a flat plane with an image. Specular highlights and shadows of a flat plane will not like part of the scene, unless your goal is to make it look like a cardboard cutout in the scene. But if that's the case, it's not really obvious from your question.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I understand the limitations of using a flat image... my goal is to push the output as fast as possible... for which i feel the cheat method is most effective

Comment: Well, then just put a flat plane in the scene with the transparent parts of the image being transparent via _Alpha_ transparency. The plane will be affected by lights and throw a shadow.